# Animation Synching in hand to hand fight in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

As title suggests I am working on hand to hand fighting system. Now its just a start and I am also not professional so I have setup moves of players and enemy.
Now problem occurs when player hits enemy, it should trigger enemy "taking hit" animation. Now it triggers but both animation of "hitting" and "taking hit" at same time,so it doesn't look at it is meant to be. 
So please anyone can set me on right path of what to do for like starting of "taking hit" when "hitting" animation reaches at some key frame or any other way.
I'll post code if you require but only a suggestion or link to some documentation will do.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code is not the problem here. You should detect when the other player hits you, then set the parameter in the animator like this:

```
yourAnimator.SetBool("TakingHit", true);
```

Then in your animator, you should put the TakingHit animator and configurate the transition when the TakingHit parameter is activated.

Another thing you should considerate is that if you activate the "TakingHit" parameter bool in a loop, it will start playing the animation in a endless mode.